# type guards for optional parameters

Tags: typescript

I have the following fixture file that i have type guarded below. it has few optional properties

fixture file-

```
 {
      "profiles": [
        {
          "name": "Laakea",
          "phoneNumber": "2033719225",
          "authGroupName": "Drivers"
        },
        {
          "name": "Lkhagvasuren",
          "phoneNumber": "2033719225",
          "authGroupName": "Drivers"
        },
        {
          "name": "Joaquin",
          "phoneNumber": "2033719225"
        }
      ]
    }
```

type interface-

```
 export interface Profile {
      name: string;
      authGroupName?: string;
      phoneNumber?: string;
      email?: string;
    }
```

type guard function-

```
export function isValidProfiles(profiles: unknown): profiles is Profile[] {
  if (!Array.isArray(profiles)) {
    return false;
  }
  for (let index = 0; index < profiles.length; index += 1) {
    if (typeof profiles[index].name !== 'string') {
      return false;
    }
    if (profiles[index].email) {
      if (typeof profiles[index].email !== 'string') {
        return false;
      }
    }
    if (profiles[index].phoneNumber) {
      if (typeof profiles[index].phoneNumber !== 'string') {
        return false;
      }
    }
    if (profiles[index].authGroupName) {
      if (typeof profiles[index].authGroupName !== 'string') {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

i was wondering if i could write it better instead of all these if statements ?

Comment: ? shouldn't you be writing `profiles is Profile[]`?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wORZrW) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Types exist only before compilation so typescript can't give you automatic validation at runtime based on it's types. So there's no way to say `.name is typeof Profiles['name']`. You can shorten the code like in ^  but you have to write it yourself or rely on a validation library (never used one in ts, but validate-typescript looks to be such a thing)

Comment: @jcalz thanks for your approach, its slightly complicted for my brain, trying to process it now

Comment: that code btw allows `name: undefined` and e.g. `email: undefined` because it simply iterates over all fields and checks that the values are either string or undefined. Would get more correct if it would drop `name` from the array and do `keys.every(k => !(k in p) || typeof p[k] === "string") && typeof p['name'] === 'string'`. That would ensure name is a string and the rest are either absent or string.

Comment: @zapl The default behavior in TypeScript is that it treats "missing" and "present-with-an-`undefined`-value" as the same, so I'm implementing that.  If you really care about distinguishing that then you can write `k => !(k in p) || (typeof p[k] === 'string')` but then you will have a mismatch with what TypeScript thinks is "optional" unless you enable [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes) which I think is probably out of scope for the question.

Comment: Good point about `name`, though, I didn't notice that.  Then I'd suggest [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJ5Qkm) instead.  @Raj let me know if that works for you or not, once you have finished processing.

Comment: Depending on how crazy you want to get, you can write a whole composable type guard library and then use schema objects to defined your interfaces, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBRnbN).  That's probably overkill here, at least for the the question as asked.

Comment: I see you wrote your own answer; do you want me to write up [this solution](https://tsplay.dev/WJ5Qkm) as an answer or not?  Also, unless I hear otherwise I'm going to [edit] your question to write `is Profile[]` instead of `is Profile` like I mentioned in my first comment, since I guess you're not going to do it?

Comment: Hi @jcalz, I would like to flag your solution as the accepted answer please .my code is no where as good as the solution you provided . I also updated my question with the suggestion. 
Thank you again for taking time to help me out here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have essentially identical code for the checks against the `email`, `phoneNumber`, and `authGroupName` properties, you can refactor those checks into a single piece of code that gets run multiple times.

For example, you can make an array of the keys (strongly typed via a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) so the compiler remembers that the values in them are [literally](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"email"`, `"phoneNumber"`, and `"authGroupName"` as opposed to just `string`), and then use its [`every()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to return `true` if and only if the check works for every key, for every member of the `profiles` array:

```
function isValidProfiles(profiles: unknown): profiles is Profile[] {
  if (!Array.isArray(profiles)) { return false; }
  const keys = ["email", "phoneNumber", "authGroupName"] as const;
  return profiles.every(p => p && (typeof p === "object") && (typeof p.name === "string") &&
    keys.every(k => typeof p[k] === "undefined" || typeof p[k] === "string")
  );
}
```

Here the check I'm using is that, for each key `k`, and for each profile `p`, `typeof p[k]` is either `"undefined"` or `"string"`.  This will correctly deal with `string` properties and missing properties.  It will also accept a property whose key is present but whose value is explicitly `undefined`.  That might not be what *you* consider "optional", but TypeScript *does* by default... unless you explicitly enable [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes)... which isn't even part of [the "standard" `--strict` suite of compiler features](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict).

---

Okay, let's test it:

```
const val = [
  {
    "name": "Laakea",
    "phoneNumber": "2033719225",
    "authGroupName": "Drivers"
  },
  {
    "name": "Lkhagvasuren",
    "phoneNumber": "2033719225",
    "authGroupName": "Drivers"
  },
  {
    "name": "Joaquin",
    "phoneNumber": "2033719225"
  }
];
if (isValidProfiles(val)) {
  console.log(val.map(
    x => x.authGroupName ?? "no-auth").join(",")
  ); // "Drivers,Drivers,no-auth" 
} else {
  console.log("nope")
}
```

Looks good.  The compiler validates `val` as being a `Profile[]` and can treat is as such.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#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-HEynS4QCmwyhU3J5vH4ukFguacD1iuxTRg8E0OAYEwH5eE0xhCME3oAB78sg0FNOO9yPOIyASBIdoYAAtOOJJNPiGCgMEhz6iQhrIAA9BRxyzkWBy0dAtAHPEOEZgqVjIBAEwEL+Cz-hAgHAcR8RovqlhAA)

Comment: Thanks! This solution sound very good because maybe is the only way, but the condition is satisfied by every object with at least a 'name' property, like: { "name" : "Square", "width": 100, "height": 100 } if I am not mistaken..  Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

came up with this -

```
export function isValidProfiles(profiles: unknown): profiles is Profile[] {
  if (!Array.isArray(profiles)) {
    return false;
  }
  for (let index = 0; index < profiles.length; index += 1) {
    if (
      !(
        typeof profiles[index].name === 'string' &&
        (!profiles[index].phoneNumber || typeof profiles[index].phoneNumber === 'string') &&
        (!profiles[index].email || typeof profiles[index].email === 'string') &&
        (!profiles[index].authGroupName || typeof profiles[index].authGroupName === 'string')
      )
    ) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

this is no way as concrete and powerful as the function written by @jcalz.

Comment: What if the strings are empty? Well I suppose if they're empty strings you wouldn't use them as phone numbers and emails. But that validation should happen somewhere else.

Comment: You can simplify the code with [DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). Basically, `not (A and B)` is the same as `not A or not B`. Likewise, `not (A or B)` is the same as `not A and not B`.